# Producer-consumer pattern implementation using semaphores

Tags: design-patterns, semaphore, producer-consumer

guys! I know that the producer-consumer pattern can be implemented using the semaphore synchronization primitive. But how many semaphores and on what events are necessary for implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, there are three components to the Producer-Consumer Pattern:

1. One or more producers
2. One or more consumers
3. A shared queue of produced objects

The producers generate objects and put them in the queue. The consumers wait until there are objects in the queue to consume and then perform some action with each object. In general, the queue can be considered unbounded (i.e., can store unlimited objects).

At its most basic level, a single, [mutually-exclusive (mutex)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) semaphore is needed that acts as the signal for the queue. This mutex allows only one client to acquire the mutex at a time. The producer creates an object, acquires the mutex, enqueues the object, and then releases the mutex. The consumer acquires the mutex, removes one element from the queue, and then releases the mutex.

The pseudocode for the producer is:

```
produce(queue, mutex):
    object := createObject()
    mutex.acquire()
    queue.enqueue(object)
    mutex.release()

consume(queue, mutex):
    mutex.acquire()
    object := queue.pop()
    mutex.release()
    handle(object)
```

This conceptual model becomes more complex when we introduce the idea of a bounded queue (i.e., there is a limit on the number of objects that can be stored in a queue). This requires that we protect the consumers from popping from the queue when there are no objects in the queue and protect the producers from enqueuing when the queue is full.

To accomplish this, we have to introduce the idea of a counting semaphore. We then create two new semaphores:

1. `empty`: Initialized with the maximum capacity of the queue
2. `full`: Initialized to 0

As a new item is enqueued, the `full` semaphore is incremented and the `empty` semaphore is is decremented. The `full` semaphore tracks how many filled slots there in the queue and the `empty` semaphore tracks the number of empty slots in the queue. When a producer enqueues a new object, it decrements the `empty` count and increments the `full` count. The consumer does the opposite when popping from the queue.

For the bounded use case, pseudocode becomes:

```
produce(queue, mutex, full, empty):

    object := createObject()

    empty.decrement()
    mutex.acquire()

    queue.enqueue(object)

    mutex.release()
    full.increment()

consume(queue, mutex, full, empty):

    full.decrement()
    mutex.acquire()

    object := queue.pop()

    mutex.release()
    empty.increment()

    handle(object)
```